# Set image to specific dimensions

Tags: matlab

I have a collection of images all different sizes. How to I convert them all to the same size? Note I don't just want to scale them down. I am aware of the `imresize` function but not sure if it can be used to get specific dimensions.

Comment: "How to I convert them all to the same size? Note I don't just want to scale them down" How else do you wish to convert them all to the same size?

Comment: imresize does have options to specify dimensions: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html#buxulax-1 ; if you do know the size you want to use, you could 'imresize' all your images using the known constant size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the 'Position' property using

```
set(gcf, 'Position', [x0 y0 width height])
```

where [x0 y0 width height] are the four values that set the position on the screen and height and width of the figure.
You should do this for every figure you open, since `gcf` is get current figure.